# Safely terminate the app to have normal start after it

Tags: android, terminate

I have several static and non-static variables in my app. when I terminate the app by clicking on the right button in the android control bar:[image]

and drag the app out, the next start of the app is complately normal (as expected), but when use:

```
    ((Activity)MainDisplay.getContext()).finish();
```

the app is finalized (but still in RAM) and during the next start there are some UI problems (for instance, by changing the activity, the UI-elements of the first activity are still shown).

Is there any idea how to fix it?

should I maybe clear all the variables before finish()?

Comment: IMO it's more an issue of handling your Activities lifecycle callbacks properly. Hard to say without your code, though...

Comment: You're not supposed to have static variables that mess with your application if you close and re-open it.

Comment: Use System.exit(0) after finish().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finish` only closes the activity you call it on, it does not terminate your app. Note that terminating your app by yourself is not usual, you should be able to deal with pausing and resuming. If you really do want to terminate your app, I think the closest you will get is `System.exit(int)`. The int represents an error, 0 means the program ended OK

Comment: I have tested `System.exit(0);`, it works. thanks! but you said its not usual, so what should I do to pause the app?

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with the Android Activity lifecycle, but you might want to take a look at it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: you mean I should somehow manage my variables in onPause() and onResume() instead of killing and creating of the app, isn't it? if so, is there any advantage with pause/resume or any potential problem witrh kill/create method?

Comment: That is usually how it should be done in Android. For example, if your app is running and you receive a phonecall, your app will be paused. When the phonecall is ended, your app will be resumed. If you kill your app instead of pausing it, your user has to start over after the phonecall.

Comment: @DEADC0DE: but I meant the cases that not because of running an app with higher priority but because the user doesn't need the app anymore and  want to end working with app (maybe until several hours)

Comment: In that case it is still expected behavior to resume an application or it has been killed by Android itself because of inactivity or reclaiming memory. I don't think whether you can detect that your app is not going to be used for several hours or that it is paused because of a phonecall. If you really want to end it, I think you need an explicit menu option